# How to connect database in vb 2012

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim conStr As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Pode\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Northwind.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(conStr)
        conn.Open()  
        MessageBox.Show("Success")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Why error at `conn.Open()`?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The error states that it cannot reach the server. You might want to check whether the instance name is correct and whether the service is running.

Comment: see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/using-an-user-instance-on-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/ `To use the User Instance functionality you need to enable it on the SQL Server. This is done by executing the following command: sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '1'. To disable the functionality execute sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '0'.`